# Docker Build: too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Running `docker build -t my_docker .`  gives me:

```
(MyEnv) D:\Projects\Coding\Python\ProjectFolder>docker build -t my_docker .
[+] Building 1.6s (6/10)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 184B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1.6s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 122B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3@sha256:797aee34488c660ebaf5b88e622fdd458e65bb3c2500d48f9fbb3711e8688a1e                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [2/6] ADD __main__.py /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
------
 > [2/6] ADD __main__.py /:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/jlho2vmj3yjif98hkwc0yqzyq/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
```

folder structure:

```
ProjectFolder
  .gitignore
  __main__.py
  db.py
  Dockerfile
  friend.py
  http_request.py
```

The Dockerfile I used:

```
FROM python:3

ADD __main__.py /
ADD db.py /
ADD friend.py /
ADD http_request.py /

RUN pip install pymongo

CMD [ "python", "./__main__.py" ]
```

Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d

---

Ignore this:

I have write some text so I post this, due to it being mostly code

Comment: What does your _Dockerfile_ contains?